# UIImageView Transform Scale

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a UIButton that when pressed, will make a UIImageView scale slightly larger and then back to its normal size. It's working, but I'm running into a problem where the image eventually keeps getting slightly smaller the more you press the button.

How can I change the code so that the image doesn't get smaller as you press the button? Here's the code I have to scale the image slightly larger and then back to normal:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.2];
myImage.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(myImage.transform, 1.03, 1.03);
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.2];             
myImage.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(myImage.transform, 0.97, 0.97);
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's math. Scaling something by `1.03 * 0.97` results in scaling factor of `0.9991` and not `1.0`. Either use `1.0/1.03` as your second scaling factor or just set `myImage.transform` to the identity transform (assuming you are not applying other transformations to that view).

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried saving first transform?

And then instead of using `CGAffineTransformScale` to shrink your `UIImageView` you just use your saved transform?

```
        CGAffineTransform firstTransform = myImage.transform;

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.2];
        myImage.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(myImage.transform, 1.03, 1.03);
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.2];
        myImage.transform = firstTransform;
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are suffering from a limitation in floating point arithmetic and cumulative matrix operations.  You will never be able to represent 3/100, only approximate it with values like, `0.03`, `0.033`, and `0.0333`.

For your problem it would be better to set the second transform to the `CGAffineTransformIdentity`