# iOS - Enlarge view (Screenshot provided)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIImageView Transform Scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059266/uiimageview-transform-scale)

I am trying to achieve something similar to the screenshot down below.

[image]

I have tried to do this by simply changing the view's frame property and increasing its width and height but it

1) does not really enlarge the view and its subviews it just increases the size 
2) It only increases its size from the left so it does not look even

Also is there a way I can have this animated? I could just place it in `UIView's` `animateWithDuration:` block right?

Comment: @Daij-Djan Not really, I never really knew that term 'scale' so it didnt come up when I searched "Enlarge view xcode", trust me, I do my research

Comment: k.. I would still mark it as such but you might be right and many dont know the term 'to scale'.

Comment: @Daij-Djan Of course I knew the actual english term 'to scale' its just that I didnt know that was the property/method to use in Xcode otherwise I would have straight searched it up in the docs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 approaches you can take -

1. If you are using standard `UITableView` then simply use [Managing the Reordering of Rows](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html)
2. If you are not using  `UITableView` and are doing something more custom with `UIViews` then
   what you need is a property called `scale`. Scaling a view is done using Core Graphics Affine transforms when you're looking to affect the UIView (as opposed to the layer which use Core Animation transforms).

To scale a view use - this scales the view to 2x.

```
// 2x
[yourView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0)];
```

To translate, use

```
// Move origin by 100 on both axis
[yourView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(100.0, 100.0)];
```

You can also play around with `alpha` to set it to say 0.5 to give it that extra cool look you have put in the screenshot.

To animate these, wrap them in an animation block. If you want to transform the view with both of these, then you need to concatenate them.

Comment: Yeah Im not using a table view. Yes, I have actually had set the alpha 0.8 to make it semi transparent, I just didnt know what this property was and this helped! Thanks! (I can accept in 6 mins)

Comment: i have modified my answer to make it more comprehensive. please read again...

Answer (score 1):

apply a transformation to the view's layer :)
that can be also be animated :) in fact, it implicitly is!

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.view.transform, 2,2);
```